# What does "parts like the Red Sea" mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms

This video (https://youtu.be/_nRtCVJIToA?t=416) is saying

> "Make way" basically means move. "Make way".
>   Okay? "I'm coming through, make way!"
>   So I'm coming through a large crowd of people, and I'm running, and I shout:
>   "Make way!" and everybody sort of parts like the Red Sea.

Although "parts like the Red Sea" seems to be an idiom, google results does not give any explanation. So, what does "parts like the Red Sea" mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*parts like the Red Sea* refers to the [biblical story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossing_the_Red_Sea) of Moses and Israelites fleeing, in which they had to cross the Red Sea.

In order to accomplish this, Moses divided the sea into 2 parts, and pushed them away from each other, as to make a path for them to cross.